# Why can't we assign the value to a non-initialized string within a for loop in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, c++14

I'am learning c++ and I've a question like why can't we initalize a given string in a for loop.

```
string s, result;

cin >> s;

for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
    result[i] = s[i];
}

cout << result;
```

There simply won't be cout ofcourse. Because result string never got initialized in a for loop? Please explain why?
The following code, instead will be execute

```
result = s;
```

Comment: You could just add `result.resize(s.size())` before the loop...

Comment: As an aside, the `result` string is not "non-initialized", but merely empty. A `std::string` has a constructor that makes sure it is initialized, even if never given a value.

Comment: @BoP I haven't learnt about std:: functions/methods yet. If you have some good article links, can you please link them up?
Thanks for the input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`result` has the length `0` so using the [subscript operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at) to dereference and assign any element (except assigning `\0` to the terminating `\0`) has *undefined behavior*.

If you want to append a `char` to the `string`:

```
result += s[i];
```

Comment: Ohh god! How could I miss this!! Thank you for pointing this out. It helped alot.